# Is it possible to spawn a powered redstone dust

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been trying to find a way to 'pick locks' for a server class, I plan on making a skill book that contains commands for that class, for lock picking I was thinking about having a powered red stone dust appear to unlock doors, but how would I summon a powered red stone dust? Is it possible?

Comment: Just summon a redstone torch?

Comment: Or a redstone block?

Comment: No. If you manage to setblock it, it will immidiatley go off... without poweringanything

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do it with a redstone torch, which I think would work better and would be more reliable. For a torch, since you probably want it to be where the player is standing, you should do

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ setblock ~ ~ ~ redstone_torch
```

this should set a redstone torch at the player's location.

Comment: Why use `@e[c=1]`? `@p` would work just fine here, and be slightly more efficient.